# Enforce NetworkPolicies to control access to pods in Azure ACS cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, acs, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I am trying to setup NetworkPolicy to control access to pods running in acs cluster. The cluster is created using acs-engine and networkPolicy=azure.

The contents of the json file used to create the cluster:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "vlabs",
  "properties": {
    "orchestratorProfile": {
      "orchestratorType": "Kubernetes",
      "kubernetesConfig": {
        "networkPolicy": "azure"
      },
      "orchestratorRelease": "1.9"
    },
    ...
}
```

The network policy that I am applying is to deny all ingress traffic to pods in my namespace:

```
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
 kind: NetworkPolicy
 metadata:
   name: default-deny
 spec:
   podSelector: {}
   policyTypes:
   - Ingress
```

The required restrictions are not effected with this NetworkPolicy.

If this even possible with "networkPolicy": "azure"?

Can someone point to right direction to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

After exploring I found that Azure CNI policy does not support Kubernetes network policies. The solution is to use CNI that supports it eg Calico.

[Container networking capabilities of Azure CNI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/container-networking)